# Use of &ampersand and square bracket in printf

Tags: c, printf

I came across the following code in an MCQ quiz,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int j =2, k =4;
    printf(&j["Programming"], &k["Theory"]);
    k = j ^ 3;
    if (k == j)
        printf(&k["Practical"], "Trytosolve");
    else
        printf(&j["Problem creation"]);
    return 0;
}
```

where ampersand is used in the beginning itself and outside the quotes ("") of printf statement. I am only aware of the traditional use of printf statement and its format specifiers.
I tried to run this code, and it showed no error but this warning:
`format not a string literal and no format arguments`

and the following output

`ogrammingoblem creation` (this was one of the options in multiple choices)

I tried to search for such use, but could not find. Can someone explain this use of & and square brackets?

Comment: Hint: `j["Programming"]` is the same as `*(j + "Programming")`. Which is a pointer arithmetic operation

Comment: `man printf` under Format of format string, explains that the format has an optional *shift state*. `j == 2` so the shift sate of the first format string output beginning 2-characters from the beginning of `"Programming"` (i.e. `"ogramming"`) and the test `k == j` fails causing the `else` printing to output starting with a shift state of `2` outputting `"oblem creation"` giving you the output you see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say we have an array `a` and a variable `i` of integral type, then `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`, i.e. we can obtain the `i`th element of `a` by decaying `a` into a pointer to its first element, incrementing that pointer by `i` and dereferencing the result. This it true because arrays occupy contiguous addresses in memory.

Now, as it turns out, `i[a]` is also equivalent to `a[i]`, this is more of a "trick" that nobody (to my knowledge) would ever use in production. It's sort of intuitively justifiable that this would be the case because `a[i] == *(a + i) == *(i + a) == i[a]`.

So then, `&j["Programming"] == &(*(j + "Programming"))`. And because dereferencing a pointer and then taking it's address is a noop, this is `j + "Programming" == "Programming" + j == "ogramming"`, because strings are just arrays of characters.

Same for the other branch, which is executed because `2 ^ 3 == 1 != 2`.

Comment: Why nothing of the second string `"Theory"` gets printed in `printf(&j["Programming"], &k["Theory"]);`? Actually I am confused as to why there are two strings inside `printf`.

Comment: @swag2198: The first argument to `printf` is the "format string", all following arguments are inserted into the format string at positions where it contains format specifiers beginning with `%`. Since "ogramming" contains no such format specifiers the second argument is simply ignored.

Comment: Ooh, I get it! So like if there were some "...%s..." in the first string, the second one would be printed too right?

Comment: @swag2198: Yes, exactly (but if there were more format specifiers than additional arguments, that would lead to undefined behavior).

Comment: Thanks Peter, learned something new about printf today, I had come across questions on i[a] format, but I did not realize it was being applied here because I was not used to seeing printf like that.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this example program will show you the math behind the scenes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int j=2, k=4;
    char *p1 = "Programming";

    // Print the address of j
    printf("&j = %p\n", &j);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Pointer arithmetic\n");
    // Print the address of "Programming"
    printf("p1                = %p\n", p1);
    // Print the value of j
    printf("j                 = %8d\n", j);
    // Print the result of the pointer computation
    printf("&j[\"%s\"] = %p\n", p1, &j[p1]);
    // Print the result of the equivalent pointer computation
    printf("p1 + j            = %p\n", p1 + j);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Print strings\n");
    // Print "Programming" after skipping the first two letters
    printf("&j[\"%s\"] = %s\n", p1, &j[p1]);
    // Print "Programming" after skipping the first two letters
    printf("p1 + j            = %s\n", p1 + j);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
&j = 0x7fffb3325aa8

Pointer arithmetic
p1                = 0x4006e4
j                 =        2
&j["Programming"] = 0x4006e6
p1 + j            = 0x4006e6

Print strings
&j["Programming"] = ogramming
p1 + j            = ogramming
```